# How may I functionally transform array of objects into a different structure

Tags: arrays, swift, functional-programming

I've got an array of fonts which each have a familyName and a fontName.

I would like to transform them into an array of tuples in the form (familyName: String, fontNames: [String]).

I feel like there should be an easy functional way to do this, but can't work it out. The closest I've got is two calls to `reduce`: First into a dictionary and then into an array.

```
let dictionary = fonts.reduce(into [String : [String]]() ) { result, font in
    let array = result[font.fontFamily] ?? []
    result[fontFamily] = array + [font.fontName]
}

let array = dictionary(into: [(String, [String])]() ) { result, element in
    result.append( (element.key, element.value.sorted()) )
}.sorted { $0.0 < $1.0 }
```

I'm also sorting the array of tuples and the array of fontNames in the array of tuples.

Is there a way I can avoid the intermediary dictionary?

Many thanks.

**Update**
I created a playground to show sanjaykmwt the results of their suggestions:

```
struct Font {
    let family: String
    let name: String
}

let fonts = [
    Font(family: "ABC", name: "abc"),
    Font(family: "ABC", name: "def"),
    Font(family: "ABC", name: "ghi"),
    Font(family: "XYZ", name: "xyz"),
    Font(family: "XYZ", name: "uvw")
]

let sortedFamily = fonts.sorted(by: { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
    return lhs.family < rhs.family
})

let dict = sortedFamily.map({["family":$0.family,
                              "fonts":$0.name]})

print("dict: \(dict)")
```

Output:

```
dict: [["family": "ABC", "fonts": "abc"], ["family": "ABC", "fonts": "def"], ["family": "ABC", "fonts": "ghi"], ["family": "XYZ", "fonts": "xyz"], ["family": "XYZ", "fonts": "uvw"]]
```

Comment: you fonts is struct  and you have an array of struct

Comment: I have given the shortest possible answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if You have an array of `Fonts` with  `fontFamily`,  `fontName`

you can make `grouping` then `map`

```
 // Array Of Fonts Example

        let array = [Font.init(fontFamily: "Cago", fontName: "AA"),
                                     Font.init(fontFamily: "Cago", fontName: "CCCC"),
                                     Font.init(fontFamily: "Mango", fontName: "AAsss"),
                                      Font.init(fontFamily: "Mango", fontName: "mngoo")]

         // Grouping

        let groupedByFamilayName = Dictionary.init(grouping: array) {$0.fontFamily}

        // Map
        let arrayOfTuple =  groupedByFamilayName.map { (key,array) -> (String,[String]) in
                            return (key,array.map({$0.fontName}))
                        }

     print(arrayOfTuple)
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about Dictionary.init(grouping: array)

Answer (score 2):

Expanding (or contracting!) on Abdelahad Darwish's answer…

```
let tuples = Dictionary(grouping: fonts) { $0.family }
    .map { (familyName: $0.key, fontNames: $0.value.map { $0.name }) }

print(tuples)
```

> ```
> [(familyName: "XYZ", fontNames: ["xyz", "uvw"]), (familyName: "ABC", fontNames: ["abc", "def", "ghi"])]
> ```

Comment: Thanks, this is approximately what I have now, plus a bit of dealing with optionals that I forgot to mention.

Comment: Nice coding Ashley

Answer (score -2):

```
    let sortedFamily = fonts.sorted(by: { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
        return lhs.family < rhs.family
    })

    let dict = sortedFamily.map({["family":$0.family,"fonts":$0.fonts.sorted()]})
```

try and print the dict you will get everything sorted

if you want even shorter it can be:

```
  let dict = fonts.sorted(by: { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
        return lhs.family < rhs.family
    }).map({["family":$0.family,"fonts":$0.fonts.sorted()]})
```

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question. The question is about the transform of the data structure, not the sorting.

Comment: this gives you both the things you want if you only want to transform then you can use this instead:    `let dict = fonts.map({["family":$0.family,"fonts":$0.fonts]})`

Comment: You refer to this $0.fonts which doesn't exist.

Comment: for you it is `$0.fontFamily` and `$0.fontName`

Comment: That just produces an array of dictionaries, each with one "family" and one "fonts" (which is a single font). At no point in the code are you merging the fontNames into one array (per familyName).

Comment: Please see my update. The output is an array of dictionaries. I was hoping for the names to be grouped by family into tuples of type (String, [String])